# jUnit, Testing the "new" reference

Tags: java, junit, new-operator

Suppose you have a method like

```
public Something copy () {
  return new Something();
}
```

In your jUnit, you have

```
Something s1 = new Something();
Something s2 = s1.copy()
```

Other then

```
assertTrue (s1 != s2);
assertTrue (s2 != null);
assertTrue (s1.toString().equals(s2.toString)));
```

Is there any additional way you can confirm that a **NEW** reference is returned by a copy()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is sufficient to check they're not the same, but there's also an assertion built into JUnit:

```
assertNotSame(s1, s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure use `Assert.assertTrue(s1, s2)`

Moreover this is *the* way to compare. It calls Something.equals() internally and throws exception is `equals` returns false.

Comment: I think you're missing the "they mustn't be the same reference" part - and `assertTrue` isn't the assertion you mean either, I suspect.

Comment: But if Something overloads equals it is likely that the above would not produce the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Hamcrest-style:
[sameInstance](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/hamcrest/core/IsSame.html#sameInstance%28T%29)

Answer (score 0):

Another great way for testing things like these is the Mockito test framework (http://code.google.com/p/mockito/)

It allows you to verify that only certain things get called N number of times, or not at all with something like:

`Mockito.verify(mockOne, times(1)).mockedFunction();`

Which verifies that `mockOne` had its `mockedFunction` called exactly once.